# hat is the proper structure for Parcel Delivery schema if your delivery contains multiple tracking numbers?

Tags: schema.org

It is possible for our orders to contain multiple SKU's as well as multiple tracking numbers per SKU on an order.

I have been referencing https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/parcel-delivery. We are also using the JSON-LD format.

```
{  
   "@context":"http://schema.org",
  "@type":"ParcelDelivery",
  "deliveryAddress":{  
     "@type":"PostalAddress",
     "name":"John Frank",
     "streetAddress":"24 Willie Mays Plaza",
     "addressLocality":"San Francisco",
     "addressRegion":"CA",
     "addressCountry":"US",
     "postalCode":"94107"
  },
  "originAddress":{  
     "@type":"PostalAddress",
     "name":"John Frank",
     "streetAddress":"25 Willie Mays Plaza",
     "addressLocality":"San Francisco",
     "addressRegion":"CA",
     "addressCountry":"US",
     "postalCode":"94107"
  },
  "expectedArrivalFrom":"2013-03-10T12:00:00-08:00",
  "expectedArrivalUntil":"2013-03-12T12:00:00-08:00",
  "carrier":{  
     "@type":"Organization",
     "name":"FedEx",
     "url":"http://fedex.com/"
  },
  "itemShipped":{  
     "@type":"Product",
     "name":"iPod Mini",
     "url":"http://apple.com/ipad32gb",
     "image":"http://apple.com/images/ipad32gb.jpg",
     "sku":"B00DR0PDNE",
     "description":"iPod Mini 32Gb White",
     "brand":{  
        "@type":"Brand",
        "name":"Apple"
     },
     "color":"white"
  },
  "trackingNumber":"3453291231",
  "trackingUrl":"http://fedex.com/track/3453291231",
  "potentialAction":{  
     "@type":"TrackAction",
     "target":"http://fedex.com/track/3453291231"
  },
  "hasDeliveryMethod":"http://schema.org/ParcelService",
  "partOfOrder":{  
     "@type":"Order",
     "orderNumber":"176057",
     "merchant":{  
        "@type":"Organization",
        "name":"Bob Dole",
        "sameAs":"http://www.freebase.com/m/0fhkx"
     },
     "orderStatus":"http://schema.org/OrderInTransit"
  }
```

}

I checked previous questions on SO and can not seem to find an answer on google or in their official documentation or schema.org. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry for the ridiculous typo in the subject :(

Comment: My only guess is replicating the entire block of JSON, but it would be repeating a lot of the same info and it would seem they would have a way to include multiple items, unless I am just missing something obvious.

Comment: Note that you can [edit] your question to correct typos etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I am wrong but after some research I am quite certain you just need to replicate the same json snippet for each parcel in the order. This is how it would work if you were not using JSON-LD so it makes sense it would work the same way. Cheers.